# CKSubscription returns error that query must have at least one firing mode when using FiresOnce

Tags: swift, cloudkit, cksubscription

I have this code.  Which works when creating a subscription with a firing mode of FiresOnRecordCreation... but getting error on FiresOnce.. the error is "Query Subscriptions must have at least one type of firing mode"

My goal is that I have a photo.  When the first rating of the photo occurs i want to get a notification.  I do not want to use FiresOnRecordCreation on the reference as for every rating there will be a notification which is too many.  I just want the first notification for the first rating received.

```
    let database = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"owningPhoto == %@", ref)
    let subscription = CKSubscription(recordType: "PhotoRatings", predicate: predicate, options: .FiresOnce)
```

xcode crashes on the subscription but on with FiresOnce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

besides the .FireOnce you should also indicate if that's for creation, update or deletion. So the call should be something like:

```
   let subscription = CKSubscription(recordType: "PhotoRatings", predicate: predicate, options: [.FiresOnce, .FiresOnRecordCreation, .FiresOnRecordUpdate, .FiresOnRecordDeletion])
```

Comment: sir, you are a scholar!